# Keep a MemoryMappedFile Alive after process terminates

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

Is it possible to keep a `MemoryMappedFile` alive after process terminates?
For example, i want to create a `MemoryMappedFile` once and then use it in a different processes. These processes can terminate and restart, but i want to synchronize the data stored in `MemoryMappedFile` across these processes.

Comment: If you back the data with an actual file (not a carved out piece of virtual memory) then yes. Otherwise, no. The file mapping will live as long as *some* process has an open handle to it (not necessarily the process that created it) but if *all* processes terminate and there's no handle anymore, then the file mapping goes poof.

Comment: So, to do it:

     MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(...); // Create file form `real` file

    MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(...); // And then use it like this

    


@Jeroen Mostert, right?

Comment: If you can dictate when the memory mapped file is first created, then yes. If it's first come, first serve, you need to be slightly trickier to avoid a race condition: `CreateFromFile` could fail if the mapping already exists, but then `OpenExisting` could still fail if the mapping ceases to exist in between. This may require a loop to be safe where you call `OpenExisting`/`CreateFromFile` until you get no `FileNotFoundException`. There is no `.CreateOrOpen` overload for the file-backed case, for some reason.

Comment: That's basically why it is a *file*.  It doesn't have to be, you can ask for the data to be backed by the paging file.  But if it needs to survive then you don't want that option.  In practice you almost always need a "server" style manager process, the one that owns the MMF and can do something reasonable when any client process crashes without saying goodbye nicely.  Pretty important, unexpected failure is pretty hard to deal with and you can rarely do anything but a controlled shut-down.  That server then doesn't need a file.